# How to calculate very long numbers in Python

Tags: python, math, gpu, biginteger, numba

I am trying to calculate `Pollard rho` number using python for very long integers such below one

`65779646778470582047547160396995720887221575959770627441205850493179860146690755880473849736210807898494458426111244201404810495587574110361900128405354081638434164434968839614760264675889940272767106444249`

I have tried to calculate on my `intel core i9 10980HK` CPU, which results for few minutes high load work without any success. I am trying to use `numba` with `@njit` decorator to connect `RTX 2070 super` (on laptop) but it gives below error.

`- argument 0: Int value is too large:`

Here the code:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

def pgcd(a,b):
    if b==0:
        return a
    else:
        r=a%b
        return pgcd(b,r)

def pollardrho(n):
    f = lambda z: z*z+1
    x, y, d = 1, 1, 1
    c = 0
    while d==1:
        c += 1
        x = f(x) % n
        y = f(f(y)) % n
        d = pgcd(y-x, n)
    return d, c

def test_time(n):
    t = datetime.datetime.now()
    d, c = pollardrho(int(n))
    tps = datetime.datetime.now() - t
    print(tps, c, d)

file = open("some_powersmooths_large.txt", "r")

for line in file.readlines():
    if not line.startswith("#"):
        print(line)
        print("\n")
        test_time(line)
        print("\n")
```

How can I handle this type of big number calculations.

Comment: Your number is a prime.

Comment: You need to understand the limitations of the algorithms you're using. Leaving aside the fact that your input is prime, the Pollard Rho algorithm applied to a composite number `n` typically takes time proportional to the square root of the smallest prime factor of `n`. As such, *no* amount of optimization is going to make Pollard Rho effective for a general 680-bit input. (You can do the math: supposing that after eliminating tiny primes the smallest prime factor is ~200 bits, for example, you'd need ~2^100 operations. How many operations per second is that, to finish in a year, say?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Part 1** (of 2, see Part 2 below).

Numba works only with 64-bit integers at most, it has no big integer arithmetic, only Python has. Big integers will be supported in future versions as developers of Numba promise. You need big integer arithmetics because you have very large integers in your inputs and calculations.

One optimization suggestion for you is to use [GMPY2](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) Python library. It is highly-optimized library of long arithmetics, considerably faster than regular Python implementation of long arithmetics. For very large integers for example it implements multiplication using [Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) which is fastest available algorithm of multiplication.

But GMPY2 can be a bit challenging to install. Most recent precompiled versions for Windows are available [by this link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gmpy). Download .whl file for your version of Python and install it through pip, e.g. for my Windows 64-bit Python 3.7 I downloaded and installed `pip install gmpy2-2.0.8-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`. For Linux it is easiest to install through `sudo apt install -y python3-gmpy2`.

After using GMPY2 your code will become as fast as possible, because this library code is almost fastest in the world. Even Numba (if it had long arithmetics) would not improve more. Only faster formulas and better algorithm can help to improve further, or smaller input integers.

But your example large integers is a way to large for your algorithm even with GMPY2. You have to choose smaller integer or faster algorithm. I've run your algorithm and number for 5 or more minutes and didn't get result. But still if before result would be in 1 hour with regular Python then after using GMPY2 it may be done in 10 minutes or faster.

Also not very sure but probably in your algorithm `f(f(y)) % n` should be equivalent to `f(f(y) % n) % n` which should be computed probably faster as it will do twice shorter multiplication. But this needs extra checking.

Also your large integer appeared to be prime, as proven by [Primo](http://www.ellipsa.eu/public/primo/primo.html) elliptic curve based primality proving program, it proved primality of this integer in 3 seconds on my PC. Primo only proves primality (with 100% guarantee) but doesn't factor the number (splitting into divisors). Factoring numbers can be done by programs [from this list](http://gilchrist.ca/jeff/factoring/index.html), these programs implement fastest known factoring algorithms, if some links are dead then Google those programs names.

Just wrap all integers `n` into `gmpy2.mpz(n)`. For example I improved your code a bit, wrapped into `gmpy2.mpz()` and also made a loop so that all divisors are printed. Also as an example I took not your large prime but a much smaller - first 25 digits of [Pi](https://www.piday.org/million/), which is composite, all of its divisors are printed in 7 second on my PC:

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow66111479#main.py)

```
import datetime, numpy as np, gmpy2

def num(n):
    return gmpy2.mpz(n)
    
zero, one = num(0), num(1)
    
def pgcd(a, b):
    if b == zero:
        return a
    else:
        r = a % b
        return pgcd(b, r)

def pollardrho(n):
    f = lambda z: z * z + one
    x, y, d = one, one, one
    c = 0
    while d == one:
        c += 1
        x = f(x) % n
        y = f(f(y)) % n
        d = pgcd(y - x, n)
    return d, c

def test_time(n):
    n = num(int(n))
    divs = []
    while n > 1:
        t = datetime.datetime.now()
        d, c = pollardrho(num(int(n)))
        tps = datetime.datetime.now() - t
        print(tps, c, d, flush = True)
        divs.append(d)
        assert n % d == 0, (n, d)
        n = n // d
    print('All divisors:\n', ' '.join(map(str, divs)), sep = '')

test_time(1415926535897932384626433)

#test_time(65779646778470582047547160396995720887221575959770627441205850493179860146690755880473849736210807898494458426111244201404810495587574110361900128405354081638434164434968839614760264675889940272767106444249)
```

Output:

```
0:00:00 2 7
0:00:00 10 223
0:00:00.000994 65 10739
0:00:00.001999 132 180473
0:00:07.278999 579682 468017117899
All divisors:
7 223 10739 180473 468017117899
```

---

**Part 2**

Reading Wikipedia articles ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) and [here](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B0)), I decided to implement a faster version of Pollard-Rho algorithm.

My version implemented below looks more complex but does twice less divisions and multiplications, also on average does less iterations of loop in total.

This improvements result in running time of `3` minutes for my test case, compared to original OP's algorithm with running time of `7` minutes, on my laptop.

My algorithm is also randomized, meaning that instead of witness 1 or 2 it takes random witness in range `[1, N - 2]`. In rare cases it may fail as said in Wikipedia then I rerun algorithm with different witness. Also it uses [Fermat primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test) to check if the input number is prime, then doesn't search for any more divisors.

For tests I used input number `p` generated by code `p = 1; for i in range(256): p *= random.randrange(2, 1 << 32)`, basically it is composed of `256` factors each `32-bits` at most.

Also I improved both algorithms to output more statistics. One of statistics params is `pow` which shows the complexity of each step, pow of 0.25 tells that if divisor is `d` then current factoring step spent `c = d^0.25` iterations to find this divisor `d`. As told in Wikipedia Pollard-Rho algorithm should have on average `pow = 0.25`, meaning that complexity (number of iterations) of finding any divisor `d` is around `d^0.25`.

In next code there are also other improvements like providing a lot of statistics on the way. And finding all factors in the loop.

My version of algorithm for my test case has average pow of `0.24`, original previous version has `0.3`. Smaller pow means doing less loop iterations on the average.

Also tested my version with and without GMPY2. Apparently GMPY2 gives not much improvement over regular Python big integer arithmetic, mainly because GMPY2 is more optimized for really big numbers (tens thousands of bits) (using Fast Fourier Transform multiplication, etc), while here number are not to big in my test. But still GMPY2 gives speedup around `1.35x` times providing running time of `3` minutes compared to almost `4` minutes without GMPY2 for same algorithm. To test with or without gmpy2 you need just to change inside `def num(n)` function either to `return gmpy2.mpz(n)` or to `return n`.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow66111479var2#main.py)

```
import datetime, numpy as np, gmpy2, random, math
random.seed(0)

def num(n):
    return gmpy2.mpz(n)
    
zero, one = num(0), num(1)

def gcd(a, b):
    while b != zero:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def pollard_rho_v0(n):
    f = lambda z: z * z + one
    n, x, y, d, c, t = num(n), one, one, one, 0, datetime.datetime.now()
    while d == one:
        c += 1
        x = f(x) % n
        y = f(f(y)) % n
        d = gcd(y - x, n)
    return d, {'i': c, 'n_bits': n.bit_length(), 'd_bits': round(math.log(d) / math.log(2), 2),
        'pow': round(math.log(max(c, 1)) / math.log(d), 4), 'time': str(datetime.datetime.now() - t)}
    
def is_fermat_prp(n, trials = 32):
    n = num(n)
    for i in range(trials):
        a = num((3, 5, 7)[i] if i < 3 else random.randint(2, n - 2))
        if pow(a, n - 1, n) != 1:
            return False
    return True
    
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm
# https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B0
def pollard_rho_v1(N):
    AbsD = lambda a, b: a - b if a >= b else b - a
    N, fermat_prp, t = num(N), None, datetime.datetime.now()
    SecsPassed = lambda: (datetime.datetime.now() - t).total_seconds()
    for j in range(8):
        i, stage, y, x = 0, 2, num(1), num(random.randint(1, N - 2))
        while True:
            if (i & 0x3FF) == 0 and fermat_prp is None and (SecsPassed() >= 15 or j > 0):
                fermat_prp = is_fermat_prp(N)
                if fermat_prp:
                    r = N
                    break
            r = gcd(N, AbsD(x, y))
            if r != one:
                break
            if i == stage:
                y = x
                stage <<= one
            x = (x * x + one) % N
            i += 1
        if r != N or fermat_prp:
            return r, {'i': i, 'j': j, 'n_bits': N.bit_length(), 'd_bits': round(math.log(r) / math.log(2), 2),
                'pow': round(math.log(max(i, 1)) / math.log(r), 4), 'fermat_prp': fermat_prp, 'time': str(datetime.datetime.now() - t)}
    assert False, f'Pollard-Rho failed after {j + 1} trials! N = {N}'

def factor(n, *, ver = 1):
    assert n > 0, n
    n, divs, pows, tt = int(n), [], 0., datetime.datetime.now()
    while n != 1:
        d, stats = (pollard_rho_v0, pollard_rho_v1)[ver](n)
        print(d, stats)
        assert d > 1, (d, n)
        divs.append(d)
        assert n % d == 0, (d, n)
        n = n // d
        pows += min(1, stats['pow'])
    print('All divisors:\n', ' '.join(map(str, divs)), sep = '')
    print('Avg pow', round(pows / len(divs), 3), ', total time', datetime.datetime.now() - tt)
    return divs

p = 1
for i in range(256):
    p *= random.randrange(2, 1 << 32)
factor(p, ver = 1)
```

Output:

```
................

267890969 {'i': 25551, 'j': 0, 'n_bits': 245, 'd_bits': 28.0, 'pow': 0.523,
     'fermat_prp': None, 'time': '0:00:02.363004'}
548977049 {'i': 62089, 'j': 0, 'n_bits': 217, 'd_bits': 29.03, 'pow': 0.5484,
     'fermat_prp': None, 'time': '0:00:04.912002'}
3565192801 {'i': 26637, 'j': 0, 'n_bits': 188, 'd_bits': 31.73, 'pow': 0.4633,
     'fermat_prp': None, 'time': '0:00:02.011999'}
1044630971 {'i': 114866, 'j': 0, 'n_bits': 156, 'd_bits': 29.96, 'pow': 0.5611,
     'fermat_prp': None, 'time': '0:00:06.666996'}
3943786421 {'i': 60186, 'j': 0, 'n_bits': 126, 'd_bits': 31.88, 'pow': 0.4981,
     'fermat_prp': None, 'time': '0:00:01.594000'}
3485918759 {'i': 101494, 'j': 0, 'n_bits': 94, 'd_bits': 31.7, 'pow': 0.5247,
     'fermat_prp': None, 'time': '0:00:02.161004'}
1772239433 {'i': 102262, 'j': 0, 'n_bits': 63, 'd_bits': 30.72, 'pow': 0.5417,
     'fermat_prp': None, 'time': '0:00:01.802996'}
2706462217 {'i': 0, 'j': 1, 'n_bits': 32, 'd_bits': 31.33, 'pow': 0.0,
     'fermat_prp': True, 'time': '0:00:00.925801'}
All divisors:
258498 4 99792 121 245864 25 81 2 238008 70 39767 23358624 79 153 27 65 1566 2 31 13 57 1776 446 20 2 3409311 814 37 595384977 2 24 5 147 3738 4514 8372 7 38 237996 430 43 240 1183 10404 11 10234 30 2615625 1263 44590 240 3 101 231 2 79488 799236 2 88059 1578 432500 134 20956 101 3589 155 2471 91 7 6 100608 1995 33 9 181 48 5033 20 16 15 305 44 927 49 76 13 1577 46 144 292 65 2 111890 300 368 430705 6 368 381 1578812 4290 10 48 565 2 2 23606 23020 267 4186 5835 33 4 899 6288 3534 129064 34 315 36190 16900 6 60291 2 12 111631 463 2500 1405 1959 22 112 2 228 3 2192 2 28 321618 4 44 125924200164 9 17956 4224 2848 16 7 162 4 573 843 48 101 224460324 4 768 3 2 8 154 256 2 3 51 784 34 48 14 369 218 9 12 27 152 2 256 2 51 9 9411903 2 131 9 71 6 3 13307904 85608 35982 121669 93 3 3 121 7967 11 20851 19 289 4237 3481 289 89 11 11 121 841 5839 2071 59 29 17293 9367 110801 196219 2136917 631 101 3481 323 101 19 32129 29 19321 19 19 29 19 6113 509 193 1801 347 71 83 1373 191 239 109 1039 2389 1867 349 353 1566871 349 561971 199 1429 373 1231 103 1048871 83 1681 1481 3673 491 691 1709 103 49043 911 673 1427 4147027 569 292681 2153 6709 821 641 569 461 239 2111 2539 6163 3643 5881 2143 7229 593 4391 1531 937 1721 1873 3761 1229 919 178207 54637831 8317 17903 3631 6841 2131 4157 3467 2393 7151 56737 1307 10663 701 2522350423 4253 1303 13009 7457 271549 12391 36131 4943 6899 27077 4943 7723 4567 26959 9029 2063 6607 4721 14563 8783 38803 1889 1613 20479 16231 1847 41131 52201 37507 224351 13757 36299 3457 21739 107713 51169 17981 29173 2287 16253 386611 132137 9181 29123 740533 114769 2287 61553 21121 10501 47269 59077 224951 377809 499729 6257 5903 59999 126823 85199 29501 34589 518113 39409 411667 146603 1044091 312979 291569 158303 41777 115133 508033 154799 13184621 167521 3037 317711 206827 1254059 455381 152639 95531 1231201 494381 237689 163327 651331 351053 152311 103669 245683 1702901 46337 151339 6762257 57787 38959 366343 609179 219749 2058253 634031 263597 540517 1049051 710527 2343527 280967 485647 1107497 822763 862031 583139 482837 1586621 782107 371143 763549 10740361 1372963 62589077 1531627 31991 1206173 678901 4759373 5877959 178439 1736369 687083 53508439 99523 10456609 942943 2196619 376081 802453 10254457 2791597 3231757 2464793 66598351 1535867 16338167 1138639 882953 1483693 12624373 35717041 6427979 5653181 6421873 1434131 1258889 108462803 859667 64298779 261810191 5743483 32314969 5080721 8961767 68011043 7528799 2086957 41618389 19999663 118428929 45556487 40462109 22478363 29039737 17366957 77805557 12775951 50890837 22666991 14892133 691979 133920733 115526921 29092501 2332124099 16835209 101301479 29987047 160734341 35904857 12376361 17774983 2397907 525367681 245240591 48159641 45590383 87274531 69160309 256092673 7430783 588029137 91286513 75817271 393556847 1183839551 71513537 593809903 200299807 161799857 537099259 21510427 335791301 382965337 156133297 180373937 75136921 364790017 174932509 117559207 601612421 54539711 2107325149 566372699 102467207 321156893 1024847609 1250224901 1038888437 3029169139 345512147 4127597891 1043830063 267890969 548977049 3565192801 1044630971 3943786421 3485918759 1772239433 2706462217
Avg pow 0.238 , total time 0:03:48.193658
```

---

**PS**. Also decided to implement minimalistic but fast version of Pollard-Rho factorization algorithm, pure Pythonic, ready for copy-pasting into any project (for example of factoring first 25 digits of [Pi](https://www.piday.org/million/)):

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow66111479var3#main.py)

```
def factor(n):
    import itertools, math
    if n <= 1:
        return []
    x = 2
    for cycle in itertools.count(1):
        y = x
        for i in range(1 << cycle):
            x = (x * x + 1) % n
            d = math.gcd(x - y, n)
            if d > 1:
                return [d] + factor(n // d)
print(factor(1415926535897932384626433))
# [7, 223, 180473, 10739, 468017117899]
```

Comment: Hi @Arty, thanks for answer, just wanted to know the calculation for above mentioned number took 3 seconds on your PC with Primo to just check whether its prime?

Comment: Also I used `conda` to install `gmpy2` and it worked well!

Comment: @ArenHovsepyan Calculation in Primo (I linked it too in my answer for download) takes 3 seconds. It is the time to PROVE that it is prime. Proving is a guaranteed procedure, same like trial division by all `x <= sqrt(n)` is also a prove for primality. Unlike pseudo primality probable testing algorithms (like Miller-Rabin and Fermat) algorithms in Primo are not probable, they are guaranteed, Primo even prints Certificate for you and scientists use it often. And yes it took 3 seconds for Primo to prove that it is prime. Primo uses elliptic curve primality tests, which are fastest in the world.

Comment: @ArenHovsepyan Also, Primo doesn't factor the number. It only tells, in a very fast way, if it is guaranteed prime or guaranteed composite. To factor a number (to find actual divisors) there are other programs, [here is a list](http://gilchrist.ca/jeff/factoring/index.html) of fastest programs for factoring, in that list links may be dead then you have to Google names of those programs to find them.

Comment: @ArenHovsepyan I just updated my answer. Did two things - 1) instead of your large prime number I use a smaller example of first 21 digits of [Pi](https://www.piday.org/million/) number, program splits it into divisors in 1 second,   2) also modified your algorithm (see code snippet in my answer) a bit to make a loop so that all divisors are printed.

Comment: @ArenHovsepyan Just now I updated a lot my answer. Added **Part 2** that implements a faster version of Pollard-Rho algorithm, according to Wikipedia suggestions. It is `2.35x` times faster than your original algorithm (for my test it runs 3 minutes, while your allgorithm takes 7 minutes). Also my version does on average less iteration loops. Also there are other improvements, like providing a lot of statistics.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the operation in `pollardrho` is very inefficient, I am not surprised that the operation takes a while.
However, I don't know that particular function, so I don't know if it could be made more efficient.

In Python, integers have an arbitrary length.
What this means is that they can be of any length, and Python itself will handle storing it properly using 64-bit integers (by spreading them over multiple of them).
(You can test this for yourself by for example creating an integer that cannot be stored in a 64-bit unsigned integer, like `a = 2**64`, and then checking the output of the `a.bit_length()` method, which should say `65`)

So, theoretically speaking, you should be able to calculate any integer.
However, because you are using Numba, you are limited to integers that can actually be stored within a 64-bit unsigned integer due to the way Numba works.
The error you are getting is simply the number becoming too large to store in a 64-bit unsigned integer.

Bottom line: Without Numba, you can calculate that number just fine. With Numba, you cannot.
Of course, if you only want to know roughly what the number is, and not precisely, you can instead just use floats.

Comment: You meant that `pollardrho` itself is inefficient way for desired calculation?

Comment: That function is basically reducing several numbers, which is always going to be inefficient. I however do not know the Pollard rho number, so I don't know if there is a better way. I was simply explaining why it shouldn't be surprising that the operation can take several minutes.
Having said that, the main problem here is that you cannot calculate such large numbers with Numba.

Comment: Got your point, `pollardrho` is relatively optimized way for finding prime `gcd` numbers

Comment: Alright, then I guess it is just inherently slow, but still faster than alternatives. Given how big the numbers are, it is to be expected that calculations can take a while.

Comment: correct. anyway I think there is better way to implement

Comment: Probably. Anyway, the reason that you cannot calculate the large integers is because of Numba, not because the calculation is inefficient, as I explained in my post.